# Did Indiana Jones ever get revenge on Lao Che?

Tags: indiana-jones

Dr. Henry "Indiana" Jones, Jr. is famously betrayed by his client Lao Che at the beginning of "Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom". The conflict ends with Indy boarding a freight plane he believes is the road to freedom, but as he closes the door we see it belongs to Lao Che's freight company. The last we see of Lao Che is him laughing and signalling to the pilots.

I have read some of the Indiana Jones novels, but not all, as well as watched most episodes of "The Young Indiana Jones" show. But I don't recall any further mention of Lao Che as a villain.

**Did Indiana Jones ever get revenge on Lao Che?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No…but there may have been attempts to resolve this

Lao Che makes [remarkably few appearances](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Lao_Che#Appearances) in *Indiana Jones* titles, with none of them taking place after *Temple of Doom*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indiana_Jones_characters#Lao_Che) does have an **unsourced** claim that he was considered to reappear in what became *Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull* before the actor's death.

> Before the death of Roy Chiao, Steven Spielberg was planning to return Che in *Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull*, but he declined the idea after Chiao's death in 1999. Also, Ric Young, the actor that portrayed Kao Kan, expressed interest in reprise his role of Kan in the movie, but he declined after Roy's death.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

(I've asked "[Did Spielberg plan on having Lao Che return in Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83509/12783)" over on Movies & TV Stack Exchange, to try to find information that might corroborate this).

The promotional trailer for *[Indiana Jones and the Staff of Kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Staff_of_Kings)* shows Indy drinking at "Lao Che Cocktails" before two thugs approach saying "I heard you were looking for the boss", suggesting that he was trying to meet Lao Che.

In the final game, the [Lao Che Lounge](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Lao_Che_Lounge) is a location Indy visits, but the man himself does not appear.